# $.post and $.get only letting title be changed, not logging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following snippet of my code, I post to a link, from which it allows me to change the title, but will not call the function `info()` with the argument supplied, nor will it log in the console, please help with this code, thanks. Also, please note all the variables are defined and this code works 100% besides this, and it won't work with $.get rather than $.post either.

```
function info(text, state) { 
    $("<h4>"+text+"</h4>").appendTo("body");
    if (state != "run") {
        $("h2").text(text).fadeIn("slow").delay(30000).fadeOut();
}

$.post(buy, function(r) { 
    diff = event.timeStamp - last;
    $(document).prop('title', 'Purchased '+info['itemName']+'!');
    info('Purchased '+info['itemName']+' for '+info['expectedPrice']+' in '+diff+' milliseconds!');
    console.log('Purchased '+info['itemName']+' for '+info['expectedPrice']+' in '+diff+' milliseconds!');        
})
```

--EDIT--
If I put console.log above info, the code works excluding the info() function, so the problem is possibly there

Comment: Are there any errors in your console. I'm pretty sure there must be something wrong with your `info`
 function.

Comment: What browser are you using? Does `console.log` work before the `info` function?

Comment: Chrome, console.log works if I put it above the info function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (this pattern)

```
// var last = $.now();

function info(text, state) {
    $("<h4>" + text + "</h4>").appendTo("body");
    if (state != "run") {
        $("h2").text(text).fadeIn("slow").delay(30000).fadeOut();
    }
// missing closing `{` at OP
};

$.post(buy, function (_info) {
    // `_info` : return json object
    // `info` : function declaration name
    // diff = $.now() - last;
    $(document).prop('title', 'Purchased ' + _info['itemName'] + '!');
    info('Purchased ' 
         + _info['itemName'] + ' for ' 
         + _info['expectedPrice'] + ' in ' 
         + diff + ' milliseconds!'
         , "run");
    console.log('Purchased ' 
                + _info['itemName'] + ' for ' 
                + _info['expectedPrice'] + ' in ' 
                + diff + ' milliseconds!');
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/7vxb7336/